# Are OBJ files exported from Blender different?

Tags: export

I'm having some issues importing OBJ files from Blender into After Effects (for Trapcode). Is there any difference between the way that Blender and similar software generates OBJ files?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of issues? Can you upload a file that your having problems with? Generally OBJ is standard and blender's exporter is fine from my experience, might be a specific issue.

Comment: Well, I have uploaded two images. The first one, is how it should look, but when you close and re-launch After Effects, you find the second image. It's very strange. It seems like the coordinate system flips or get bigger, I don't know. I used to use Cinema 4D before and I never had any issue with OBJ. I usually download OBJ from Turbosquid too. So, I think it has to do with Blender OBJ, maybe something with the export settings.

Comment: so it's OK when you first import it into AfterFX, but when you return to the project it's different?

Comment: Recent versions of AfterFX have [Cinema4D (Lite)](http://www.maxon.net/products/general-information/general-information/product-comparison.html) built in. It may be worth seeing if the same thing happens using its Obj importer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem blender has in comparison with most other software is its axis differences. Blender uses +Z up, +Y forward, +X right, whereas most others are different. Maya, for example, uses +Z backward, +Y up, +X right; C4D uses +Z forward, +Y up, +X right... It's a mess.

[image: Blender]
[image: Maya]
[image: C4D]

In the export settings, you can set which axes are up and forward. By default, they follow the convention that allows them to import into Maya properly, ie -Z forward, +Y up.

After Effects may be different. I believe +Z is coming towards you and +Y is up. The point here is that you might need to experiment with the axis export settings to get the proper orientation of your object in AE.

Key point to remember is that from the front camera view, forward is going away from you, right is right, up is up. A quick and easy way to test these settings is to just use Suzanne as a test model. She's light and easily recognizable, much more so than a cube. Once you get her to export right, just use those settings for your other objects.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But I think the flip scenario is not the case, it seems like the way Blender generates and recognizes OBJ files is different. I have played around a little more with OBJ files and Blender, and I think something is wrong with the OBJ Import / Export tool. For example, I tried to import an OBJ file into Blender, and two faces disappeared. It didn't happen in Photoshop, Cinema 4D or Houdini. I'm not a developer, but I'm sure there is something weird with this add-on.

Comment: I've never had a problem with OBJs, even when I export/import a 1-GB scene, no matter the software I take it from. Maybe the normals were flipped on those two faces, I don't know. I always do cleanup to make sure everything's consistent, like normal recalculating and removing doubles.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the second problem has to do with the normals and if the 3D model is clean. The first problem I mentioned has to do with the Trapcode plugin and OBJ files from any software, not just Blender, so, it is something that Red Giant needs to solve.

Comment: Honestly, 3D software just needs to use Z up, Y forward, X right. Just simplify it for everybody and make it consistent. I'm waiting for someone to think outside the box and use Z down, X left.

Comment: does anyone know the setting then to use for 3ds MAx?